# Как доступиться к системным файлам в Android? java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, потоки-данных, root

Когда я пытаюсь что-то записать в COM-порт посредством командной строки в андроиде я просто пишу в шеле: `echo 123abc > /dev/ttyO0` и получаю это в терминале. Всё просто. Если я пытаюсь сделать то же в андроиде:

```
final byte[] request = {0x0A, 0x10, 0, (byte)0x99, 0, 0x01, (byte)0xD0, (byte)0x9D};
    final String comPortAddress = "/dev/ttyO0";
    final OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(comPortAddress);
    fileOutputStream.write(request);
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.close();
```

То получаю исключение:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/ttyO0: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
W/System.err:     at keppowertesting.com.modbustesterapp.TryStreams.go(TryStreams.java:15)
W/System.err:     at keppowertesting.com.modbustesterapp.MainActivity.button2Click(MainActivity.java:49)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err: **Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
W/System.err:   ... 19 more
```

У меня в манифесте есть строка:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="25"/>
```

Но её явно недостаточно. Рут-доступ на устройстве присутствует.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы используете методы, доступные только руту, то в `AndroidManifest.xml` добавьте соответствующую строчку:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER">
```

`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` относится к dangerous permissions, поэтому, для получения этого разрешения (при `targetSdk 23` и выше), кроме соответствующей строки в `AndroidManifest.xml` необходимо еще запросить это разрешение у пользователя в [рантайме](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Вот набросал небольшой пример запроса необходимого Вам разрешения:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;

    private Button mButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != getPackageManager().PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == getPackageManager().PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешение получено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешение отклонено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку запрашивается разрешение, после реакции пользователя отображается `Toast` с информацией о том, получено ли запрошенное разрешение или нет.

Comment: Спасибо за старания, но это ничего не изменило. У меня API17, и никакого запроса не выскакивало. Я также пробовал упростить задачу и работать с простым файлом /test.txt, но то же самое. И что интересно, в логах Supersu нет моей программы, то есть попыток сделать что-то от имени root не было со стороны программы.

Comment: @Eugene, `targetSdk 17`? или на устройстве `api level 17`? То, что Вашей программы нет в логах, вполне логично, так как она не может обратиться к файлам, так как нет доступа. Вы все-таки попробуйте мой совет.

Comment: И попробуйте еще в манифест добавить `android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER`.

Comment: Это всё не то. Вот, что помогло: 'if (!file.canRead() || !file.canWrite()) {
   try {
    Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    if ((su.waitFor() != 0) || !file.canRead() || !file.canWrite()) {
     System.out.println("Всё равно нет!");
     return;
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {}
  }'

Comment: API level 17. targetSDK 25. Только после вызова 'Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")' на экране всплыл запрос за root-доступ от Supersu, я разрешил, и тогда уже заработало.

Comment: +1, надо запросить su. Пермишн ACCESS_SUPERUSER только для старых андроидов не помню точно каких